# Neo4j - Update relationship properties dynamically from JSON

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to create/update properties of an existing Neo4j relationship object dynamically from JSON key values (i.e. without listing all `SET` statements), but this creates a new relationship with a new id on each update pass. What I would like is to keep only one relationship.

JSON object "properties.json"

```
{"prop1":"val1","prop2":"val2"}
```

Query with dynamic properties, though creating many relationships :

```
CALL apoc.load.json("properties.json") YIELD value as props
WITH props
MERGE (client:Client {name: 'Alice'})-[r:KNOWS]->(client:Client {name: 'John'})
ON CREATE
SET r = props // I want such an expression
```

Result (if r was already existing):

```
id> 123
prop1   val1
prop2   val2

id> 124
prop1   val1
prop2   val2
```

But when the properties are set statically, then it works.

Query with static properties creating one relationship:

```
...
ON CREATE
SET
 r.prop1 = "val1",
 r.prop2 = "val2"
// But I don’t want this explicit list
```

Results satisfying (if r was already existing):

```
id> 125
prop1   val1
prop2   val2
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: what is r.props? Doing this: SET r.props = v will not change the value of prop1 and prop2.  What is the value of v?

Comment: @jose_bacoy: Thanks, my bad. Corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you update the properties prop1 and prop2 properly.  There is no shortcut.

```
CALL apoc.load.json("properties.json") YIELD value as props
WITH props
MERGE (client:Client {name: 'Alice'})-[r:KNOWS]->(client:Client {name: 'John'})
ON CREATE
SET r.prop1 = props.prop1, r.prop2 = props.prop2
```

What you can do is to create new cypher statements (e.g. using python or java code) to update those properties "dynamically".

Comment: I am looking to allocate those values **dynamically** (as I might have hundreds of properties), i.e. without explicitly listing all `SET` statements.

Comment: you can write a python or java code to create those cypher statements for you "dynamically".  For strictly cypher, there is no way to change the name of the properties that you want to update. You want a different cypher statements for different property names that you will update.

Comment: Thank you. Would you pls add those details in your answer and I'll mark it solved.

Comment: Also a reference would be welcome. Thanks.